# Failed to fetch error in chainlink functions registration

Tags: chainlink

I can't register my Chainlink Functions Subscription, I keep getting this error

"Failed to fetch"

[image]

I have tried both Mumbai and Ethereum Sepolia test-network

Comment: There could be muddy state in your wallet. A quick way tocheck is to open an incognito window, install metamask totally fresh, create a throwaway wallet and try and register that way ? will help isolate the root cause

Comment: Thanks @ZeusLawyer, I tried another browser and it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, having your MetaMask wallet set to activate on-click at the extension setting doesn't work with Chainlink Functions subscription creation.
[image]

To fix the issue, set it to work on all sites.